# How can I adjust the font size according to the size of the text field?

Tags: swift, fonts, resize, textfield

I want a text field to fill in the users' name and the resizing works, but the font size does not change with it. How can I do this so the font size gets adjusted, for example, 160 for an iPad and 50 for the iPhone 5 automatically?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P14eD.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjSfa.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set font size for `wR hR` 160. To handle font for specified device, you should catch iPhone device model.

[image]

You should care about constraints if UITextField for iPad/iPhone in Storyboard.

Or use next code, for example, in `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)`:

```
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Or here:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

     textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
     return true
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work the way I want it to :/ it starts way too big this way

Comment: I can't add more than 2 variations of this. Is that right or is my xcode bugging?

Comment: You can add with plus `+` button just left from `Font` property.

Comment: There isn't a way that it fits perfectly for every device there is?

Comment: It is difficult task to handle it for each device, but you should use some mean strategy: set `Min Font Size` property, set font size for needed variations (`+`), use `textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` for some cases.